# Display All content in angular material tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on angular material tabs. I noticed the behaviour of the tabs as it display the content of the active tab in the DOM.

I need to display all the content of the angular material tab in the DOM including inactive tabs. But data should be shown only the active tab.

Firstly is that possible in the angular-material-tabs. If yes, please provide any solution

Comment: Yes, it is possible in angular material tabs. You can get the currently active tab index in your component. On the base of the active tab index, you can make the async call.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you provide any solution

Comment: please check this solution. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tab-example-zwe1r6

Comment: Thanks Prashant. But I don't use routing for tabs. My tab data is basic angular tab component. The answer you provided didn't helped me

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same ploblem, need all tab child elements loaded in DOM